# slideshow with many animation issue

Tags: android, slideshow, sharedpreferences

I have image slideshow app im trying to let the user choose from many animation in setting activity so i used SharedPreferences to achieve that , when i run the app its open but it show just first image and quickly exit app without force close , im new for android development , and i think im missing something in my code ,

so please any help to fix that will be appreciated,thanks.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.six,R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine,

        };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);             
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
  }

private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", true);             
boolean animation = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation", false);
boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", false);        

if (animation_two == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    currentimageindex++;

    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  
      finish();
}else if(animation_one == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    currentimageindex++;

    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

                finish();

}else if (animation == true) {
     slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);

          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  
                finish();

    } else if(animation_two == false && animation == false && animation_one == false){
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    currentimageindex++;

    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);

  slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  
  finish();
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.SETTING");
        startActivity(p);
    break;

        }
return false; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your code and it will work fine as below:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
    R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,
    R.drawable.six,R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine,

    };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);             

}      

private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", true);             
            boolean animation = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation", false);
            boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", false);

 if (animation == true) {   
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);               
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if(animation_one == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_two == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

}else if(animation == false && animation_one == false && animation_two == false){
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage); 
}
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
  }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.action_settings:
    Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.SETTING");
    startActivity(p);
break;

    }
return false; 
}
}
```

hope help you